# NiFi extract from PDF to text

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

Used 3 processors to do this

1. GetFile
2. ExecuteScript
3. PutFile

In the Execute Script processor-- Used groovy script and followed the steps in this link below. It works fine but the last few pages / last few lines of the last page does not get extracted. Tried it with different Pdf files and ran into same issue.

```
   import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

def doc, info
def s  = new PDFTextStripper()

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
 doc = PDDocument.load(inputStream)
 info = doc.getDocumentInformation()

        s.writeText(doc, new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream))
    } as StreamCallback
)
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.page.count', "${doc.getNumberOfPages()}")
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.title', "${info.getTitle()}" )
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.author',"${info.getAuthor()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.subject', "${info.getSubject()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.keywords', "${info.getKeywords()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.creator', "${info.getCreator()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.producer', "${info.getProducer()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.date.creation', "${info.getCreationDate()}" );
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.date.modified', "${info.getModificationDate()}");
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'pdf.trapped', "${info.getTrapped()}" );   
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-extract-text-metadata.html

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The problem could be in a document itself. For example the text could be in an image. And there is no writer.flush() that could be a reason of the problem. Please share your code in the question.

Comment: where should I use Write.flush? The pdfs I tried did not have images in them.

Comment: Try this:  `outputStream.withWriter{w-> s.writeText(doc, w) }` instead of corresponding line in your code

Comment: @daggett great. That did the miracle. Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems in this line of code:

```
s.writeText(doc, new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream))
```

you are creating the OutputStreamWriter that internally has a buffer that transferred to underlying output stream on call of `OutputStreamWriter.flush()` or `OutputStreamWriter.close()`. None of those methods called in your code.

You can use groovy method `withWriter` to close writer after closure finished:

```
outputStream.withWriter{w-> s.writeText(doc, w) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code but I received the following error :

```sh
unable to resolve class PDFTextStripper(). This is jars file in path of module directory:
jempbox-1.8.12.jar
fontbox-1.8.12.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

It looks to me that there are missing dependence.

Comment: i make to follow your code but i received error : unable to resolve class.
Is there miss dependent file
[my error][1]
[my groovy file][2]
[my process][3]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4zYj.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7daL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryIyY.png